# what plugin that they used for navigation on atmospherejs.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have found cool site and have very interested with effect that they put on navigation (when you click on menu icon on the top left). can you guys tell me how to achieve this? I'm just learning js so I assume they use some kind of plugin like html2canvas to grab the screen.

I really appreciate if you can help :)

Comment: this is an application, built on meteor.js no some concrete plugin

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because asking us to help you reverse engineer someone else's website to reproduce their effects is inappropriate.  Instead, you could show your attempts at duplicating theirs, and perhaps we could help you improve them.

Comment: you shd have googled it first

Comment: @g.d.d.c  yes, sorry for that:)  I'll try to update my question

Comment: @Lakshay believe me I did, but because my limitations best that I get is html2canvas

Comment: @jhyoramona no probs..did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the same menu effect by [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/18/perspective-page-view-navigation/).
You can also download the source from their site.

Comment: Oh wow that's beyond my expectations!  Thanks dude